# What's this (yellow, rubbery thing - pic attached) I found in my Box Hedge plant?

Tags: identification, fungus

[image]

I am cutting back a hedge plant today and found this in the middle of it. It's sort of rubbery, not attached to the plant but just nestling in there.

It has sort of a top part, and a corkscrew-like "tail".

Is this some kind of fungus? (It has that sort of stretchy, slimy texture that fungi sometimes have, but I'm certainly no expert!) Is it safe to touch and how to get rid of it?!

Edited to add: I took it out as per the comment, here's a picture of it with my hand for scale.
[image]

Comment: It's quite difficult to see it clearly, looks a bit like a mini corncob plastic thing - if its not attached to the plant, don rubber gloves or gardening gloves and lift it out, take another photo of it on its own. I'd cut or break it  and see what it is - it won't cause you harm if you don't ingest it if its of organic origin. Wear a dust mask in case of spores if you're concerned,, but it doesn't look like any fungal growth I recognise

Comment: I'll put a vote in for "plastic or rubber manmade" by the looks of it, but I suppose it could be some weird seed-pod.

Comment: Is there any part of the world where it's still April 1st...?

Comment: Is this last picture all part of this thing?  If so, yup, it must be a fishing lure though what fisherman would think THIS would be attractive to any fish I just dunno.  My son the herpetologist agreed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing you found is a fishing lure! A bird probably dropped it there.

Comment: Haha, really? I'm such a city dwelling n00b that doesn't do things like fishing, I didn't recognise it! It might as well have come from space!!

Answer (score 0):

I vote for the end of a rattlesnake during shedding!!  I'll go ask my son who is a herpetologist...

Comment: April's fool prank?